# Kivy: What does touch.ud means

Tags: python, kivy

Just starting kivy framework, in the kivy [painting app tutorial](https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/firstwidget.html) there is this line of code:

```
touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))
```

Could someone kindly clarify on what `touch.ud` exactly means?
Using `print(help(touch.ud))` returns

> Help on EnhancedDictionary in module kivy.input.motionevent object:
>
> class EnhancedDictionary(builtins.dict) 
>   ...

Putting all that together, still not sure what is happening. Could someone please explain in particular the “`ud`” part. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through touch parts is the parameter that provides the events `on_touch_XXX` and is [`MotionEvent`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html#kivy.input.motionevent.MotionEvent), so if you want to find information you should go to that part of the documents, checking the [`docs`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html#kivy.input.motionevent.MotionEvent.ud) you get the following:

> [**ud = None**](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html#kivy.input.motionevent.MotionEvent.ud)
>
> User data dictionary. Use this dictionary to save your own data on the touch.

Then the description tells us that if you want to share some information that you want to use in the other events on_touch_xxx it is correct to save it in that dictionary:

```
def on_touch_XXX(self, touch):
    touch.ud["some_info"] = some_value

def on_touch_YYY(self, touch):
    value = touch.ud["some_info"]
    print(value)
```

In the case of the particular example, the instance of the Line created in `on_touch_down` is saved, since `on_touch_move` you need it to add more points.

Comment: So on `on_touch_down` it save the coordinates as a “starting point” and then on `on_touch_move` it adds the coordinates to draw the actual line! Thank you sir!

Comment: @belle 
on_touch_down creates the line and for this you need at least one point. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: Sorry!  It has been a while since the last time i asked a question in here. Thanks :)